# SSIS - System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request

Tags: sql-server, sockets, ssis

I'm using a Web Service Task in order to get a SessionID from an API developed by the company I work for. I have created a `HTTP Connection Manager` and specified the server URL that points to the `?wsdl` file.

I am getting below error. The server is very strict and even with sending mails from `SQL Server` I've had some issues.

**Error**

> Web Service Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message:
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:9914
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(EndPoint
>   ipEndPoint)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String
>   machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage
>   msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream,
>   ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   Entersoft.Framework.Platform.ESLightSession.GetSessionID(String
>   AppServerID, String DatabaseID, String CompanyID, String BranchID,
>   String UserID, String Password, DateTime LoginDate, String LangID,
>   Boolean ServerSideSession, String SrvURL, String ForceGID)    at
>   Entersoft.Framework.Platform.ESLightSession.GetSessionID(String
>   AppServerID, String DatabaseID, String CompanyID, String BranchID,
>   String UserID, String Password, DateTime LoginDate, String LangID,
>   Boolean ServerSideSession, String SrvURL)    at
>   ESWebServices.ESWebServices.GetSessionIDWithServerUrl(String
>   appServerID, String databaseID, String companyID, String branchID,
>   String userID, String password, String langID, String serverUrl)    at
>   ESWebServices.ESWebServices.GetSessionID(String appServerID, String
>   databaseID, String companyID, String branchID, String userID, String
>   password, String langID)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---.    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser
>   taskVariableDispenser)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".